# Grouping and Transposing data in SAS EG 5.1

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I'm working in SAS EG (Proc SQL) and I have a data set that looks like this:

```
PC | Year | Frequency 
A  |  18  | 1
A  |  19  | 2 
A  |  20  | 3 
B  |  18  | 4 
B  |  20  | 5 
C  |  17  | 6
...
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
PC | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20  
A  |    | 1  | 2  | 3 
B  |    | 4  |    | 5
C  | 6  |    |    | 
...
```

With the year values becoming columns demonstrating frequency. I've played around a bit with GROUP BY but it doesn't seem to do what I need. Any help gratefully appreciated

Comment: Are you writing plain code or using the EG tools available when developing a process flow ?  You can use `REPORT` or `TABULATE` to present data in a transposed way without actually creating a new transposed data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data test;
   infile cards firstobs=2 dlm='|';
   input pc:$1. year freq;
   cards;
PC | Year | Frequency 
A  |  18  | 1
A  |  19  | 2 
A  |  20  | 3 
B  |  18  | 4 
B  |  20  | 5 
C  |  17  | 6
;;;;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary data=test nway completetypes;
   class pc year;
   freq freq;
   output out=test2(drop=_type_);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=test2 out=test3 prefix=Year;
   by pc;
   id year;
   var _freq_;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]